# alert always pop up using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem about my code in ajax.

**AJAX**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var stopTime =0;
 var scoreCheck =  function ()
    {
      $.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/checkScoreRoundOne',
      success:function(output){
        if(output !=' '){
          $('#maincontent1').html(output);
            bootbox.alert("We have a winner", function(){     
            });    
         stopTime = setTimeout(scoreCheck, 1000); 
            }
        else {
          clearTimeout(stopTime);
            }
    }
  });
}
stopTime = setTimeout(scoreCheck,1000);
 </script>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function checkScoreRoundOne(){
$id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
$battleID = $this->lawmodel->getBattle($id);
foreach($battleID as $row){
    $Rscore = $row->requestedScore;
    $Cscore = $row->challengerScore;
    if($Cscore == '1'){
        $rID = $this->lawmodel->getID($row->challengerID);
        foreach($rID as $row){
          echo $row->username."Got the correct answer";
           }
        }
    else if($Rscore == '1'){
        $cID =$this->lawmodel->getID($row->requestedID);
        foreach($cID as $row){
            echo $row->username."Got the correct answer";
          }
        }
    else 
        echo "Answer the question";
        }
}
```

My problem is ajax will always alert even it did not meet the condition in my controller.
I cant test my project if it is correct or not..Im using codeigniter..

Im new in ajax plss help..:(
**Edited**

How can i make the alert popup only when it meet the condition in my controller? :(
Like when Cscore == '1' alert will popup..

Comment: what are you trying to do? it is not obvious from your question

Comment: edited already..sorry..im not very specific..:(

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right, then this line

```
if(output !=' '){
```

in your request should be something like

```
if(output != "Answer the question"){
```

Why?
When you don't meet `$Cscore == '1'` or `$Rscore == '1'` you return the string `"Answer the question"`. And knowing that whatever you return will be the content of the `output` variable it will never be only a space `' '`!

Answer (score 0):

Move the foreach code to the model and instead use return instead of echo.

Say:
Model:

```
public function getID($row->challengerID){
 //some code
if($Cscore || $Rscore){
    foreach($cID as $row){
        return $row->username."Got the correct answer";
      }
  }else{
  return false;
  }
```